# Display array in GUI using Java

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, object, frame

I am a beginner at Java. I want to display an array of objects (of my class) in a Frame. For example, the object has a `name` field and I want to display the fields's value of all the objects in the array.

Can someone help me find a way to resolve this without necessarily providing code?

Comment: do you want to display each of the object as `JLabel` having the name as the text of the label?

Comment: Not really, to specify I have array(10)(10) and I want this array to represent a map of a room. 'name's are floor, door, desk etc.

Comment: I would suggest a `JTable`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.